# Can hide status bar on iphone but ipad when xcode is set to iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Ok. I'm going to try to ask this one more time.  Hopefully, I will not inadvertently piss off the overflow police.  this is not a duplicate question, if you read deeper into the question.

I have an iphone only app that I want to run on iphone and ipad.  It runs fine except that when I turn off the status bar it is off on the iphone but not on the ipad.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

```
I have set the keys in info.plist

UIStatusBarHidden = YES

and

UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO

I have included the following code in viewdidload in my starting view controller

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];


[self prefersStatusBarHidden];  // 10-9 to remove status bar
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Comment: I think hiding the status bar does not work on iPad. It actually releases the space of the status bar on the phone space, but the iPad status bar is shown.

Comment: I'm able to remove the status bar just fine on iPad, so its possible.

Comment: You can remove status bar on iPad, try putting it in your app delegate or view controller. iPad should not ignore this for any reason.  If not post some more code/detail on how you setting up your navigation of the app etc

Comment: I'm testing this on a one VC app. JSA what do mean by "setting up the navigation of the app"?  I can hide the status bar on the ipad if i set the app up as a universal app, but then i have to have separate storyboards for both.  if i set it as an iphone app it works fine on both except that the status bar shows on the ipad

Comment: If you are developing this as an iPhone app, the status bar won't hide on the iPad (because on the iPad the app just appears in 2x mode - still enough space to show the status bar). You can use the same storyboard for both iPhone and iPad using size classes

Answer (score 0):

The Info.Plist item should be:

```
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = YES
```